# R: run function over same dataframe multiple times

Tags: r, function, loops, reduce

I’m looking to apply a function over an initial dataframe multiple times. As a simple example, take this data:

```
library(dplyr)
thisdata <-  data.frame(vara = seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 1)
                        ,varb = seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 1))
```

And here is a simple function I would like to run over it:

```
simplefunc <- function(data) {datasetfinal2 <- data %>% mutate(varb = varb+1)
return(datasetfinal2)}
thisdata2 <- simplefunc(thisdata)

thisdata3 <- simplefunc(thisdata2)
```

So, how would I run this function, say 10 times, without having to keep calling the function (ie. thisdata3)? I’m mostly interested in the final dataframe after the replication but it would be good to have a list of all the dataframes produced so I can run some diagnostics. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with multiple identically-structured data.frames individually is a difficult way to manage things, especially if the number of iterations is more than a few. A popular "best practice" is to deal with a "list of data.frames", something like:

```
n <- 10 # number of times you need to repeat the process
out <- vector("list", n)
out[[1]] <- thisdata
for (i in 2:n) out[[i]] <- simplefunc(out[[i-1]])
```

You can look at any interim value with

```
str(out[[10]])
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ vara: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ varb: num  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
```

and, as you might expect, the final result is in `out[[n]]`.

This can be simplified slightly using `Reduce`, and adding a throw-away second argument to `simplefunc`:

```
simplefunc <- function(data, ...) {
  datasetfinal2 <- data %>% mutate(varb = varb+1)
  return(datasetfinal2)
}
out <- Reduce(simplefunc, 1:10, init = thisdata, accumulate = TRUE)
```

This effectively does:

```
tmp <- simplefunc(thisdata, 1)
tmp <- simplefunc(tmp, 2)
tmp <- simplefunc(tmp, 3)
# ...
```

(In fact, if you look at the source for `Reduce`, it's effectively doing my first suggestion above.)

Note that if `simplefunc` has other arguments that cannot be dropped, perhaps:

```
simplefunc <- function(data, ..., otherarg, anotherarg) {
  datasetfinal2 <- data %>% mutate(varb = varb+1)
  return(datasetfinal2)
}
```

though you must change all other calls to `simplefunc` to pass parameters "by-name" instead of by-position (which is a common/default way).

**Edit**: if you cannot (or do not want to) edit `simplefunc`, you can always use an anonymous function to ignore the iterator/counter:

```
Reduce(function(x, ign) simplefunc(x), 1:10, init = thisdata, accumulate = TRUE)
```

Comment: This might require setting up a new problem but how would you feed two dataframes into the reduce function? (eg. at the init point).

Comment: It is not clear to me what you intend to do: if you mean do this separately for two dataframes, then just run it twice (there's no easy robust/resilient other way); if you mean the combination of two dataframes, then it depends on whether you mean `rbind` or `cbind`-like combination.

Comment: Sorry, yes a bit hard to describe. I've outlined the problem in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242969/r-using-reduce-with-custom-function So mostly looking for more flexibility about feeding output from the function into subsequent iterations. Regardless, the above answer is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `for` loop

```
thisdata1 <- thisdata
for(i in 2:3){
   assign(paste0('thisdata', i), value = simplefunc(get(paste0('thisdata', i-1))))
 }
```

NOTE1: It is better not to create individual objects in the global environment where the operations can be done easily within a `list`.

NOTE2:  Forgot to add the disclaimer earlier

Comment: *You know* it would be far better to have a list of dataframes instead of using `assign` ...