# Using reduce with custom function

Tags: r, loops, reduce

This is an updated (and hopefully simplified) problem to one I posted earlier.

I have a custom function, the purpose of which is to optimize spend over a number of weeks, where spend is allocated to periods of high sales activity.

I'm happy with the function, but need a way to be able to iterate through the data a number of times. I was hoping to use the 'reduce' function to accomplish this but haven't had much luck.

Here is the initial data to feed into the function:

```
sales <-  data.frame(salesx = c(3000, 2250,850,1800,1700,560,58,200,965,1525)
                     ,week = seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
                     ,uplift = c(0.04)
                     ,slope = c(100))
spend <- data.frame(spend = seq(from = 1, to = 500, by = 1))
datasetfinal <- merge(spend,sales,all=TRUE)
```

And here is a somewhat simplified version of the function (all the function does is identify the best place to put $500 worth of spend based on sales activity...for each iteration I want to exclude the 'reverse' values from the spend data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(sqldf)

  optimizationfunc <- function(data) {
  datasetfinal2 <- data %>% mutate(optimized = salesx*(uplift*(1-exp(-spend/slope))))
  datasetfinal2$spend <- with(datasetfinal2, if ("reverse" %in% colnames(datasetfinal2)) spend - reverse else spend)
  datasetfinal2 <- with(datasetfinal2, if ("reverse" %in% colnames(datasetfinal2)) within(datasetfinal2, rm(reverse)) else datasetfinal2)    
  datasetfinal2$optimized2 <- datasetfinal2$optimized/datasetfinal2$spend

  datasetfinal2$spend <- ave(datasetfinal2$spend, datasetfinal2$week, FUN = seq_along)
  datasetfinal2 <- datasetfinal2 %>%  arrange(desc(optimized2))
  datasetfinal2$counter <- seq.int(nrow(datasetfinal2))

  datasetfinal3 <- datasetfinal2 %>%  dplyr::filter(counter <= 500)  %>% dplyr::mutate(value = optimized2*spend)

  datasetfinal4 <- datasetfinal3 %>% group_by(week) %>% top_n(1, value) %>% dplyr::select(-salesx)
  datasetfinal4 <- merge(datasetfinal4[, c('week', 'spend', 'optimized', 'optimized2', 'value')],sales,by="week",all = TRUE)
  datasetfinal4[is.na(datasetfinal4)] <- 0
  datasetfinal4 <- colwise(na.locf)(datasetfinal4)

  #This is a filter I want to exclude from spend in the next run. 
  #So if it is 20 for week 1 I want to exclude the first $20 of spend.
  datasetfinal4$randomfilter <- sample(100, size = nrow(datasetfinal4))
  datasetfinal4$difference <- with(datasetfinal4, randomfilter - optimized)
  datasetfinal4$difference <- with(datasetfinal4, ifelse(difference < 0, 0, difference))
  datasetfinal4$reverse <- with(datasetfinal4, round(-log(1-(difference/salesx/uplift))*slope),1)
  datasetfinal4$reverse[is.na(datasetfinal4$reverse)] <- 0
  return(datasetfinal4)
}
```

Let's run the function:

```
datasetfinal4 <- optimizationfunc(datasetfinal)
```

Now I want to use the output of the function, to join back to the original data, and filter out 'spend' that is already allocated:

```
reversefunc <- function(data1, data2) {sqldf("select a.*, b.reverse from data1 a left join data2 b on a.week = b.week") %>%  filter(spend > reverse) %>% dplyr::select(-reverse)}
datasetfinal5 <- reversefunc(datasetfinal, datasetfinal4)
```

This works fine, but I need to repeat the process a number  of times (lets say 5) eg.

```
datasetfinal6 <- optimizationfunc(datasetfinal5)
datasetfinal7 <- reversefunc(datasetfinal5, datasetfinal6)
```

I was hoping the reduce function would work here but haven't had much luck. If I don't get any bites I'll have a go at simplifying it further.

There is a solution for a simple version of this problem here:
[R: run function over same dataframe multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134735/r-run-function-over-same-dataframe-multiple-times)

**UPDATE**
So based on the answers below and elsewhere, this is pretty much what I want. Seems a little inefficient as running optimizationfunc twice:

```
iterationFunc <- function(x,...){
optimizedData <- optimizationfunc(x)
finalData <- reversefunc(x, optimizedData)
return(finalData)}

out <- Reduce(iterationFunc, 1:10, init=datasetfinal, accumulate = TRUE)
out2 <- lapply(out, function(x) optimizationfunc(x))
out3 <- lapply(out2, function(x) sum(x$value))
out4 <- ldply(out3, data.frame)
```

Comment: To use `reduce` you want your data frames in a list, then just `dfList %>% reduce(reversefunc)`

Comment: `dfList <- list(datasetfinal,datasetfinal4)`

Comment: Per your update, why do you think you need `reduce`? `reduce` combines lists using a specified function. My understanding is that you're trying to recursively iterate your optimization function to generate your final data frame.

Comment: I would like to run diagnostics on each iteration (ie. optimizedData dataframe) produced...at some point the optimization will stop producing improvements. This seems best done on a list of dataframes which I felt the reduce function was close to achieving, but open to suggestions...

Comment: You can store the output df from the recursive function like `dfList <- list(dfList, list(funcOut))`, you probably want `map()` to run diagnostics on the list output of dataframes though (and not `reduce()`).

Comment: Check the update in my question, the code now outputs what I'm after. The 'value' variable is a little meaningless as I'm using a random sample instead of the recursive filter function it my actual code. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to obtain the same output and happy to accept an answer that does.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(purrr)

#put data into a list
dfList <- list(datasetfinal,datasetfinal4)

#pass list to reversefunc
finalDF <- dfList %>% reduce(reversefunc)

identical(datasetfinal5,finalDF)
[1] TRUE
```

I don't think this is really what you're trying to do though. Here's one way of iterating the function, I used your object names, which makes it kind of confusing, but I'm pretty sure it works. Note that `datasetfinal5` is being re-written with the new output each time, and `for` loop assumes 10 iterations.

```
iterationFunc <- function(x){
  datasetfinal6 <- optimizationfunc(x)
  datasetfinal7 <- reversefunc(x, datasetfinal6)
  datasetfinal5 <- datasetfinal7
  return(datasetfinal5)
}

for (i in 1:10){
  iterationFunc(datasetfinal5)
  finalData <- datasetfinal5
}
```

**Below with better variable names:**

```
finalData <- datasetfinal4    

iterationFunc <- function(x){
      optimizedData <- optimizationfunc(x)
      finalData <- reversefunc(x, optimizedData)
      return(finalData)
}

for (i in 1:10){
  iterationFunc(finalData)
}
```

Try to use variable names that actually give valuable information about the object. Calling everything datasetfinal[1-10] makes it really hard to keep track of what's happening each time.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use a recursion

```
rf <- function(data, n, threshold) {
           if (n <= threshold) {
                 reverse <- optimizationfunc(data)
                 new <- reversefunc(data, reverse)
                 rf(new, n+1, threshold)
           } else {
                 return(data)
           }
}

datasetfinalX <- rf(datasetfinal,1,5)
```

Your individual functions `opitimizationfunc` and `reversefunc` would still be declared outside of and before `rf`

**---RETURNING ALL REVERSE DFs----**

Adding `return(reverse)` at the end might work, but I'm not able to test it...let me know if it works?

```
rf <- function(data, n, threshold) {
           if (n <= threshold) {
                 reverse <- optimizationfunc(data)
                 new <- reversefunc(data, reverse)
                 rf(new, n+1, threshold)
           } else {
                 return(data)
           }
           return(reverse)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - would it be possible to output all dataframes produced during the process in a list? I'm more interested in the outputs from the optimizationfunc than reversefunc (which I'll then join to the original 'sales' dataframe).

Comment: Cheers, I've had a look at it. Seems to return the first dataframe - is it possible to return a list of all dataframes produced?